# outputtypehandler ( TypeError: expecting variable with array size large enough for fetch)

Tags: python-3.x, cx-oracle

Using outputtypehandler to fetch data from Oracle using Python's Cx_Oracle module but getting the following error.

**TypeError: expecting variable with array size large enough for fetch**

```
def OutputTypeHandler(cursor, name, defaultType, size, precision, scale):
    if defaultType in (cx_Oracle.DB_TYPE_TIMESTAMP, cx_Oracle.DB_TYPE_DATE):
        return cursor.var(datetime.date,cursor.arraysize)
```

Could anyone please help resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close. You want this instead:

```
def OutputTypeHandler(cursor, name, defaultType, size, precision, scale):
    if defaultType in (cx_Oracle.DB_TYPE_TIMESTAMP, cx_Oracle.DB_TYPE_DATE):
        return cursor.var(datetime.date, arraysize=cursor.arraysize)
```

The second parameter to `cursor.var()` is the *size* of the value (used for strings, not for dates). You want the *third* parameter which is the arraysize!